# Unpickle instance from Jupyter Notebook in Flask App

Tags: python, flask, jupyter-notebook, google-colaboratory, pickle

I have created a class for word2vec vectorisation which is working fine.
But when I create a model pickle file and use that pickle file in a Flask App, I am getting an error like:

> AttributeError: module `'__main__'` has no attribute 'GensimWord2VecVectorizer'

I am creating the model on Google Colab.

Code in Jupyter Notebook:

```
# Word2Vec Model
import numpy as np
from sklearn.base import BaseEstimator, TransformerMixin
from gensim.models import Word2Vec

class GensimWord2VecVectorizer(BaseEstimator, TransformerMixin):

    def __init__(self, size=100, alpha=0.025, window=5, min_count=5, max_vocab_size=None,
                 sample=0.001, seed=1, workers=3, min_alpha=0.0001, sg=0, hs=0, negative=5,
                 ns_exponent=0.75, cbow_mean=1, hashfxn=hash, iter=5, null_word=0,
                 trim_rule=None, sorted_vocab=1, batch_words=10000, compute_loss=False,
                 callbacks=(), max_final_vocab=None):
        self.size = size
        self.alpha = alpha
        self.window = window
        self.min_count = min_count
        self.max_vocab_size = max_vocab_size
        self.sample = sample
        self.seed = seed
        self.workers = workers
        self.min_alpha = min_alpha
        self.sg = sg
        self.hs = hs
        self.negative = negative
        self.ns_exponent = ns_exponent
        self.cbow_mean = cbow_mean
        self.hashfxn = hashfxn
        self.iter = iter
        self.null_word = null_word
        self.trim_rule = trim_rule
        self.sorted_vocab = sorted_vocab
        self.batch_words = batch_words
        self.compute_loss = compute_loss
        self.callbacks = callbacks
        self.max_final_vocab = max_final_vocab

    def fit(self, X, y=None):
        self.model_ = Word2Vec(
            sentences=X, corpus_file=None,
            size=self.size, alpha=self.alpha, window=self.window, min_count=self.min_count,
            max_vocab_size=self.max_vocab_size, sample=self.sample, seed=self.seed,
            workers=self.workers, min_alpha=self.min_alpha, sg=self.sg, hs=self.hs,
            negative=self.negative, ns_exponent=self.ns_exponent, cbow_mean=self.cbow_mean,
            hashfxn=self.hashfxn, iter=self.iter, null_word=self.null_word,
            trim_rule=self.trim_rule, sorted_vocab=self.sorted_vocab, batch_words=self.batch_words,
            compute_loss=self.compute_loss, callbacks=self.callbacks,
            max_final_vocab=self.max_final_vocab)
        return self

    def transform(self, X):
        X_embeddings = np.array([self._get_embedding(words) for words in X])
        return X_embeddings

    def _get_embedding(self, words):
        valid_words = [word for word in words if word in self.model_.wv.vocab]
        if valid_words:
            embedding = np.zeros((len(valid_words), self.size), dtype=np.float32)
            for idx, word in enumerate(valid_words):
                embedding[idx] = self.model_.wv[word]

            return np.mean(embedding, axis=0)
        else:
            return np.zeros(self.size)

# column transformer
from sklearn.compose import ColumnTransformer

ct = ColumnTransformer([
    ('step1', GensimWord2VecVectorizer(), 'STATUS')
], remainder='drop')

# Create Model
from sklearn.svm import SVC
from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline
from sklearn.model_selection import GridSearchCV
import pickle
import numpy as np
import dill
import torch
# ##########
# SVC - support vector classifier
# ##########
# defining parameter range
hyperparameters = {'C': [0.1, 1],
                   'gamma': [1, 0.1],
                   'kernel': ['rbf'],
                   'probability': [True]}
model_sv = Pipeline([
    ('column_transformers', ct),
    ('model', GridSearchCV(SVC(), hyperparameters,
                           refit=True, verbose=3)),
])
model_sv_cEXT = model_sv.fit(X_train, y_train['cEXT'])
# Save the trained cEXT - SVM Model.
import joblib
joblib.dump(model_sv_cEXT, 'model_Word2Vec_sv_cEXT.pkl')
```

Code in Flask App:

```
# Word2Vec
model_EXT_WV_SV = joblib.load('utility/model/MachineLearning/SVM/model_Word2Vec_sv_cEXT.pkl')
```

I tried to copy the same class into my Flask file, but it is also not working.

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn.base import BaseEstimator, TransformerMixin
from gensim.models import Word2Vec

class GensimWord2VecVectorizer(BaseEstimator, TransformerMixin):

    def __init__(self, size=100, alpha=0.025, window=5, min_count=5, max_vocab_size=None,
                 sample=0.001, seed=1, workers=3, min_alpha=0.0001, sg=0, hs=0, negative=5,
                 ns_exponent=0.75, cbow_mean=1, hashfxn=hash, iter=5, null_word=0,
                 trim_rule=None, sorted_vocab=1, batch_words=10000, compute_loss=False,
                 callbacks=(), max_final_vocab=None):
        self.size = size
        self.alpha = alpha
        self.window = window
        self.min_count = min_count
        self.max_vocab_size = max_vocab_size
        self.sample = sample
        self.seed = seed
        self.workers = workers
        self.min_alpha = min_alpha
        self.sg = sg
        self.hs = hs
        self.negative = negative
        self.ns_exponent = ns_exponent
        self.cbow_mean = cbow_mean
        self.hashfxn = hashfxn
        self.iter = iter
        self.null_word = null_word
        self.trim_rule = trim_rule
        self.sorted_vocab = sorted_vocab
        self.batch_words = batch_words
        self.compute_loss = compute_loss
        self.callbacks = callbacks
        self.max_final_vocab = max_final_vocab

    def fit(self, X, y=None):
        self.model_ = Word2Vec(
            sentences=X, corpus_file=None,
            size=self.size, alpha=self.alpha, window=self.window, min_count=self.min_count,
            max_vocab_size=self.max_vocab_size, sample=self.sample, seed=self.seed,
            workers=self.workers, min_alpha=self.min_alpha, sg=self.sg, hs=self.hs,
            negative=self.negative, ns_exponent=self.ns_exponent, cbow_mean=self.cbow_mean,
            hashfxn=self.hashfxn, iter=self.iter, null_word=self.null_word,
            trim_rule=self.trim_rule, sorted_vocab=self.sorted_vocab, batch_words=self.batch_words,
            compute_loss=self.compute_loss, callbacks=self.callbacks,
            max_final_vocab=self.max_final_vocab)
        return self

    def transform(self, X):
        X_embeddings = np.array([self._get_embedding(words) for words in X])
        return X_embeddings

    def _get_embedding(self, words):
        valid_words = [word for word in words if word in self.model_.wv.vocab]
        if valid_words:
            embedding = np.zeros((len(valid_words), self.size), dtype=np.float32)
            for idx, word in enumerate(valid_words):
                embedding[idx] = self.model_.wv[word]

            return np.mean(embedding, axis=0)
        else:
            return np.zeros(self.size)

# Word2Vec
model_EXT_WV_SV = joblib.load('utility/model/MachineLearning/SVM/model_Word2Vec_sv_cEXT.pkl')
```

GitHub code: https://github.com/Juned-Ansari/test

Pickle file: https://github.com/Juned-Ansari/test/blob/main/model_Word2Vec_sv_cEXT.pkl

Flask Web App: https://github.com/Juned-Ansari/test/tree/main/WebApp

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From https://docs.python.org/3/library/pickle.html:

> `pickle` can save and restore class instances transparently, however the class definition must be importable and live in the same module as when the object was stored.

> The following types can be pickled:
>
> - ...
> - classes that are defined at the top level of a module
> - instances of such classes ...

Considering your directory structure:

```
├── WebApp/
│  └── app.py
└── Untitled.ipynb
```

And assuming you `flask run` from within `WebApp/`, so `app` is a top-level module.

First, move `class GensimWord2VecVectorizer` to the top level of `WebApp/app.py`.

Next, in your Jupyter Notebook, import `GensimWord2VecVectorizer` and trick `pickle` to think it's from a top-level `app` module:

```py
from WebApp.app import GensimWord2VecVectorizer
GensimWord2VecVectorizer.__module__ = 'app'

import sys
sys.modules['app'] = sys.modules['WebApp.app']
```

Then you should be able to `dump` and `load` the pickle file.

## Google Colab

If it's troublesome to import local modules, do this instead:

```py
GensimWord2VecVectorizer.__module__ = 'app'

import sys
app = sys.modules['app'] = type(sys)('app')
app.GensimWord2VecVectorizer = GensimWord2VecVectorizer
```

Then you should be able to `dump` and `load` the pickle file.

Answer (score 1):

Import `GensimWord2VecVectorizer` in your Flask Web app python file.